# Adobe Illustrator Artwork file format, version 3

Tags: format, adobe, adobe-illustrator

I have an old "Adobe Illustrator Artwork file", with file format version 3:

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 
%%Creator: Adobe Illustrator(TM) 3.2
%%AI8_CreatorVersion: 22.1.0
...
```

Adding a simple circle to the file adds this code:

```
253 -433 m
253 -465.0325 227.0325 -491 195 -491 c
162.9675 -491 137 -465.0325 137 -433 c
137 -400.9675 162.9675 -375 195 -375 c
227.0325 -375 253 -400.9675 253 -433 c
b
```

Where can I find the specification of this? And in particular, for drawing a circle.

I just need to find circles of a given radius, and change its radius.
How to do this?

Comment: A quicks search yielded this link: https://www.fileformat.info/format/ai/egff.htm __ Illustrator is pretty good about opening legacy files so I do need to wonder why you don't just open the file in whatever copy of AI you have and work from there.

Comment: i see, thx! so, m (move to), 4 c (curveto--append Bezier to path), and b (Leaves closed, filled, stroked path). Got it! so it does not have the concept of "circle". I want to make a program that reads the AI file, make some changes (scaling some of the circles, not all of them), and writes a new AI file. But I guess that it's easier to make a script from within the AI software.